# How to transfer data from one server to another without downloading to local using Python?

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I'm using Paramiko to download a few images to localhost and then upload them to a server via SSH.

How to achieve it without downloading to local? As the server times out while downloading and uploading large files (> 100 mb).

Something similar to this:
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9029/how-to-wget-a-file-to-a-remote-machine-over-ssh

But in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a network structure like this:

```
local machine ---X--- machine A
              |            |
              |            Z
              |            |
              ---Y---- machine B
```

then you're currently downloading over link `X`, then uploading over link `Y`.  If `machine A` can talk directly to `machine B`, then link `Z` also exists.  This would be the case where both `machine A` and `machine B` are publicly accessible.

So you want to have `machine A` initiate a direct transfer of images to `machine B`.  At this point, it's the code running on `machine A/B` which is handling the transfer, so it's likely that a Python solution would only help you get the transfer started.

If you were doing this from the bash shell using `ssh`, you might type something like this:

```
ssh user@machineA 'scp myfile user@machineB'
```

This assumes that you have shell access to the ssh server on `machine A` and that it has the `scp` program installed.  Paramiko is only useful for making the connection to `machine A` to initiate the transfer, not for handling the transfer itself.

Something like this might work:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('machineA', username='user', password='passwd')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("scp '{imgpath}' user@machineB".format(
    imgpath='path/to/file/on/machineA')
```

**Update:**

If the images are being served from `machine A` but you don't have ssh login access, then the images can be pulled directly to `machine B` by logging into `machine B` and executing a command to fetch the image.  `wget` can typically be used for this.  So the code to do this from `localhost` might be:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('machineB', username='user', password='passwd')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("wget '{imgurl}'".format(
    imgurl='http://url.to.image/file')
```

For testing, just skip the use of paramiko and use ssh/wget directly.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but it doesn't solve the exact purpose. Let's say I've a random image url, what I'm doing right now is download the image and then upload it. How to remove that downloading to my local host phase?

Comment: Usually I'll setup the target server with a simple web page that accepts the random image URL, then write scripts to d/l the image to a specific folder.

Comment: @Hick If you don't have login access to the machine on which the images exist, you could log in to `machine B` and pull the image directly from the image server.  I've updated my answer with some details.  Not sure if this is what you're asking.

Comment: Hey! In fact we both reached at the same answer on our own. But yes, your update is exactly what I was looking for. I would also suggest to use a timeout along with wget.